# tipauni, xeCJK: loading xeCJK messes up position of IPA diacritics

Tags: xecjk, tipauni

I want to typeset a document containing some phonetic transcriptions of Chinese words. I'd like to write the words using Chinese characters, so I'm loading the `xeCJK` package for that. I'm also loading the `tipauni` package to facilitate typesetting the transcriptions (it's much faster than plonking through the actual unicode by hand).

However, I've found that loading `xeCJK` and `tipauni` together causes the positions of some IPA diacritics to be shifted too far to the right, like this:

[image]

The correct placement should be like this (what I get if I comment out `\usepackage{xeCJK}`:

[image]

If I type the unicode directly, it displays correctly; the following comes from `\textipa{\s{m}}m̩` (the second character has the unicode diacritic directly applied to it):

[image]

So this seems to be something about how `tipauni` is handling the diacritics internally, rather than something that `xeCJK` is changing about how unicode is getting rendered in general.

I've tried both orders for loading the packages, and it doesn't seem to make a difference. Is there a way to fix this? I'd much prefer to use `tipauni` over fiddling with getting the unicode right "by hand."

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[documentfont=DoulosSIL]{tipauni}
\usepackage{xeCJK} % fine if this is commented out

\begin{document}
    \textipa{\|x{m}\s{m}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I add `\showoutput` I get

```
....\TU/DoulosSIL(0)/m/n/10 m̽m̩
```

when `xeCJK` is not loaded, but

```
....\TU/DoulosSIL(0)/m/n/10 m
....\kern -0.0002
....\kern 0.0002
....\TU/DoulosSIL(0)/m/n/10 ̽
....\kern -0.0002
....\kern 0.0002
....\TU/DoulosSIL(0)/m/n/10 m
....\kern -0.0002
....\kern 0.0002
....\TU/DoulosSIL(0)/m/n/10 ̩
....\kern -0.0002
....\kern 0.0002
```

when it is. The problem is in the interchar tokens activated by `xeCJK`.

I suggest to add some optional setup at the beginning of `\textipa` (but inside the group it opens). You might propose the patch to the developers of `tipauni`.

In this case the extra setup is to locally disable `xeCJK` features.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[documentfont=DoulosSIL]{tipauni}
\usepackage{xeCJK} % fine if this is commented out

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand\textipa{ +m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \l__tipauni_extras_tl % <--- added
      \cs_set_eq:NN \* \tipaunistar
      \cs_set_eq:NN \: \tipaunicolon
      \cs_set_eq:NN \; \tipaunisemicolon
      \cs_set_eq:NN \! \tipaunibang
      \cs_set_eq:NN \| \tipaunipipe
      \cs_set_eq:NN \t \tipaunit
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__tipauni_remove_from_accents_seq
      { \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_text_accents_tl {##1} }
      \tl_set:Nx \l__tipauni_textipa_tl { \text_expand:n {#1} }
      \use:x
        {
          \exp_not:n
            {
              \escapechar = `\\
              \tl_set:Nx \l__tipauni_textipa_tl
                { \exp_args:No \__tipauni_act:n \l__tipauni_textipa_tl }
              \escapechar =
            }
          \int_use:N \escapechar
        }
      \exp_stop_f:
      \l__tipauni_textipa_tl
      \__tipauni_nontipa_search:
    \group_end:
  }

\tl_new:N \l__tipauni_extras_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\settipaextras}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__tipauni_extras_tl { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\settipaextras{\xeCJKsetup{xeCJKactive=false}}

\begin{document}

\textipa{\|x{m}\s{m}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: it's quite curious that one gets the “unsupported commands” warning for an input that only uses supported ones. Besides, the warning mentions a list of unsupported commands that appears nowhere in the manual.

Comment: I maintain `tipauni` currently. Sorry for the warnings. They are indeed strange. In fact I wonder how the package even passed the [test-suit](https://git.gnu.org.ua/tipauni.git/tree/tipauni/testfiles). I will probe more into this soon.

Comment: About the documentation, it _does_ highlight tipauni-exclusive characters. It has a note regarding it too, but maybe I should have a section for readers who are just skimming through the manual and are expecting a section directly. Will make things easier.

Answer (score 4):

You can load `xunicode-addon` (or just `xunicode`) package instead of `tipauni`, it also provides `\textipa`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{xunicode-addon}
\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}

\begin{document}

    \textipa{\|x{m}\s{m}}
    
\end{document}
```

However, there are some special commands only provided by `tipauni`, read
document of `tipauni` for details.

Or you can turn off `xeCJK` locally:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[documentfont=DoulosSIL]{tipauni}
\usepackage{xeCJK} % fine if this is commented out
% renewcommand \textipa is not recommended
\newcommand\mytipa[1]{{\xeCJKsetup{xeCJKactive=false}\textipa{#1}}}

\begin{document}

    \mytipa{\|x{m}\s{m}}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: result]